# Why is the output of free -h different from free --giga?

Tags: disk-usage, disk, swap, free

I am facing a very weird problem.

On my Fedora PC I have 12 GB swap file.

But when I issue `free -h` I get :

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.7Gi       1.8Gi       3.7Gi       409Mi       2.2Gi       5.2Gi
Swap:          11Gi          0B        11Gi
```

As you can see my swap is shown as 11 GB, where in reality I have 12 GB.

This is corrected when I use `free --giga`

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:              8           1           3           0           2           5
Swap:            12           0          12
```

Here I get the correct output.

**Why is there a difference when I use** `-h` **vs** `--giga` **?**

What is going on here ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both commands use different units: `-h` shows values in powers of 1024 (note the “Gi” suffix, for [gibibytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte)), `--giga` shows values in powers of 1000.

In your case, 12GB (gigabytes) is 12,000,000,000 bytes, which equals 11.2GiB (rounded to the closest 0.1) which `free` rounds down to 11.

You can force `free -h` to use powers of 10 with the `--si` flag:

```
free -h --si
```

`units` can perform such conversions for you:

```
$ units 12GB GiB
    * 11.175871
    / 0.089478485
```

Comment: You might mention `units` here which says 12 gigabytes == 11.175871 gibibytes and is generally very useful for such conversions.